# how to combine SOAP WCF with website in basicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

Okay, the situation is like this, I want to add an exist WCF service to an exist asp.net website, but I got a headache 400 problem:

- I've got a SOAP WCF service sending large filestream which works pretty well.

FileUploadService.cs is like this and the interface is well configured.

```
public class FileUploadService : IFileUploadService
{
    private readonly string _path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + \\sharedfiles\\";
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
    public void UploadPocoStream(PocoStream pocoStream)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(_path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_path);
            }
            using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(_path + pocoStream.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                pocoStream.Stream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                outputStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

and the PocoStream is like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class PocoStream
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }
}
```

- I'm going to combine the WCF service with an exist demo website.

Below is server property:

[image]

I added this to website's web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="test1.FileUploadService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2668/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <!-- Service Endpoints -->
      <endpoint address="FileUploadService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="test1.IFileUploadService" bindingConfiguration="haha" >
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="haha" closeTimeout="0:10:00" 
               receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferSize="65536" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000" transferMode="StreamedRequest"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

- I successfully added service reference and build a test client.

test client is like this：

```
FileUploadServiceClient a = new FileUploadServiceClient();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var b = new PocoStream() { FileName = fileName, Stream = fs };
    a.UploadPocoStream(b.FileName, b.Stream);
}
```

and the client’s app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUploadService" closeTimeout="0:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000" transferMode="StreamedRequest"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2668/FileUploadService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUploadService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IFileUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUploadService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But the result is that once run the client, I got an unexpected 400 bad request at client:
[image]

and this at server:
[image]

I think I got something wrong at the config file. Any one can help? Thanks a lot!

### Notes:

1. #### I can create file successfully, but it's empty.
2. #### I'm trying to use "Stream" transferMode to upload large file with little memory cost.
3. #### I did not set any security setting, the website is just a demo site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a customBinding instead of a basicHttpBinding. It is way more customizable.

You can use this tool to make it : http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/

Then you only have to configure your HTTP(S) transport to add Basic authentication :

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="NewBinding0">
    <textMessageEncoding MessageVersion="Soap11" />
    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000" transferMode="StreamedRequest" authenticationScheme="Basic" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Use httpsTranport only if you expose your service under SSL/TLS. Although, keep the httpTransport element.

In the client, add the username and password :

```
a.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
a.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

And then ansure that Basic Authentication is Enabled in your IIS Web Application.

Comment: Uh... I'm a newbie. Maybe I did a bad reconfigure, but I still get a 400 error.

Comment: `<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="haha">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
        <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000" transferMode="StreamedRequest" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2668/FileUploadService.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="haha"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IFileUploadService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileUploadService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>`

Comment: After a lot of trying I still got a 400 error.    
    `<customBinding>
        <binding name="haha">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647000" transferMode="StreamedRequest" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>` It tells me that I have to use "Anonymous"

Comment: Add authenticationScheme="Basic" in your httpTransport element to activate the Basic Authentication

Comment: make sense to start with config from here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: it also can be the problem with permissions on service side. http://kjellsj.blogspot.de/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html
simply debug the service, if it is allowed to write into the folder on the server

Comment: I'm sure server have full access to that path, it created a new file, but it's empty.

Comment: As it as a 400 error, the issue comes from WCF. If it was a file permission issue, it would be a 500 error.

Comment: It keeps tell me that when transferMode is set to "StreamedRequest" , I can't use credentials.

Comment: Can you two "up" my question? I want more people watch this.

Comment: What is your IIS Web application configuration ?

Comment: I'm just debugging in VS, the server property has been added to the question. "匿名" means "Anonymous"， “集成” means “Integrate”....thank you so much for wasting so much time on my question, it's very kind of you! even better if you helped me out... :) @RomEh

Comment: You should deploy your application on a local IIS if possible (look at the properties of your project). You will have more configuration options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92395/discussion-between-lulus-young-and-rom-eh).